# Patching New Node on SQL Server 2005 /Windows 2003

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

adding a third node to an active/active cluster (currently sp3, no updates).  adding the node for each virtual server through add/remove programs seems straightforward, but need to also install sp3 on the new node.  Should I run sp3 from the active node in each case, or should I run sp3 on the new node using the /passive switch ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey - the recommended process for patching a 2005 cluster node is to run SP3 on the active node.  The installer will check each node for the presence of the Service Pack and apply it only where needed.

I believe this is also what the read me file for SP3 recommends also.

Brian